# jquery autocomplete not insert id

Tags: autocomplete, dropdown

here is my code

```js
                    $(this).ready( function() {
            $("#id").autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: 
                function(req, add){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>autocomplete/lookup",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: req,
                        success:    
                        function(data){
                            if(data.response =="true"){
                                add(data.message);
                            }
                        },
                    });
                },
            select: 
                function(event, ui) {
                    $("#result").append(
                        "<li>"+ ui.item.value + "</li>"
                    );                  
                },      
            });
        });
```

i the id for selected label not inserting will , so how to retrive id to insert in a form

Comment: how to retrive the ID for insert in forum

Comment: Just fix issue by passing id selected to hidden value input and add one line for fix my code     $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.key );